# stop and start ItemCheckedevent

Tags: c#, winforms, listviewitem

I want to stop the method below before I start another method A and restart after the execution of the method A.

I did not find a way to stop/start this method below.

```
    private void CheckTrsfSelect(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
    {
        lvi = e.Item; 
        if (lvi.SubItems[2].Text == "HOTEL" && TrsfSelect == 1 &&lvi.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Blabla.");
            lvi.Checked = false;
        }
    }
```

lvi is a public listviewitem

Comment: Stop - as in, you do not want the method to be triggered when the event happen?

Comment: Yes. This Method A starts when I click a label or formload

Comment: So, I can say that you are avoiding double click to call the method twice before the previous one is finished. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Consider of using a global flag to indicate that this method is currently working to avoid duplicate call.

This way, this method cannot be called twice while it is processing the previous call.

```
bool CheckTrsfSelectIsProcessing = false;
private void CheckTrsfSelect(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!CheckTrsfSelectIsProcessing){
        CheckTrsfSelectIsProcessing = true;
        lvi = e.Item; 
        if (lvi.SubItems[2].Text == "HOTEL" && TrsfSelect == 1 &&lvi.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Blabla.");
            lvi.Checked = false;
        }
        CheckTrsfSelectIsProcessing = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish to learn if there is a way to stop/start this property inside the program but your solution make the half job. Thanks.